# How to set a Sound as Ringtone etc in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

All I can find in the internet is 8+ years old and in Java, didnt manage to find any explanation in Kotlin on how to set a mp3 file from Internal Storage as a Ringtone, Notification or Alarm.

Here is how I did it in Java:

```
    private static void changeSystemAudio(Context context, int type, File file) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, file.getName());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, false);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PODCAST, false);

        final Uri baseUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
        Uri toneUri = getUriForExistingTone(context, baseUri, file.getAbsolutePath());
        if (toneUri == null) {
            toneUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(baseUri, values);
        }
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, type, toneUri);
    }


private static Uri getUriForExistingTone(Context context, Uri uri, String filePath) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {

            cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                    .query(uri,
                            new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA},
                            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + " = ?",
                            new String[]{filePath},
                            null, null);

            if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() != 0) {

                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int mediaPos = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
                return Uri.parse(uri.toString() + "/" + mediaPos);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But what about Kotlin? Any resources on that?

Comment: Did you tried translating this by yourself into Kt first? If you have, please tell us where you got stuck/the problems that you have encountered in doing so and update the code posted in the thread.